# Creating Mock Data in the LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to use mock data in my custom LWC components but not able to use the template for:each properly in my Javascript file can some one please help me out where i am making mistake.

Below is my Code :

## HTML

```
    <template>
        <header class='slds-card__header slds-grid slds-text-title_bold slds-has-flexi-truncate'>
          
                <template for:each={testData} for:item='testDataObj'>
                    <tr class='slds-align-top' key={testDataObj.uniqueKey}>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <template if:true={testDataObj.CreatedDate}>
                                <div class='slds-truncate dv-dynamic-width'>
                                    {testDataObj.CreatedDate}
                                </div>
                            </template>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
    
            </tbody>
    
        </table>
    </template>
```

## Javascript

```
    import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
    import demoLightningTableJSON from './demoLightningTableJson.js';
    
    export default class DemoLightningTableLWC extends LightningElement {
    
        @track testData;
    
        connectedCallback() {
            this.testData = JSON.stringify(demoLightningTableJSON());
            
            console.log('Here is the data file  == '+(this.testData));
        }
    
    }
```

## JSON Javascript:

```
const testTabledata = (() => {
    return {
       ',
                
            }
            
        ]
    }
});

export default testTabledata;
```

it is coming something like this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dummyDataSet` is your first problem. This adds an extra layer in your JSON, which means your data isn't mapped right.

It should look like:

```
const testTabledata = () => 
  [
    { CreatedDate: '07/07/2020', ... },
    ...
  ];
```

Second:

```
this.testData = JSON.stringify(demoLightningTableJSON());
```

Is not right. `for:each` expects literal objects, not a JSON string. Just do:

```
this.testData = demoLightningTableJSON();
```